# Get bash autocompletion printed by stdin write

Tags: linux, node.js, bash, autocomplete

I want to write a program that will print out the autocompletions of bash.
Basically I'm writting something into bash stdin with

```
childProc.stdin.write("./myfi")
```

And would like to receive autocompletion for it like "./myfile.txt"

But `childProc.stdout` is empty after `childProc.stdin.write("\t")` so there has to be some other way to trigger autocompletion.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

Command-completion in only enabled in interactive shells. Bash is interactive if:

- Neither a script filename nor the `-c` option were specified when invoking bash, and
- both stdin and stderr are attached to terminals (as determined by `isatty()`), or
- bash was started with the `-i` flag.

In your case, `stdin` is clearly a pipe, which is not a terminal. So probably command completion has been disabled. But if it were enabled, you'd see the result on `stderr` not `stdout`.

So you could try supplying the `-i` command line option when starting your bash shell, or you could attach its stdin, stdout and stderr file descriptors to a pseudo-tty. In either case, what you will see coming back from bash will be intermingled with terminal control codes, so you'll probably want to set `TERM` to something basic (like `dumb`).

If you want to see the completions which `bash` might generate, you can use the `compgen` built-in. `compgen` does not know about the customized completion settings installed by the `complete` command, and it is not easy to get the environment set up correctly for the `-F` and `-C` function, but other than that you can probably get it to generate whatever completion lists you would like. See the [Bash manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Programmable-Completion-Builtins) for detailed option documentation.

Comment: Do you know any good ways to get autocompletion results programmatically? I'd like to write a code completion based on a REPL launched in background bash

Comment: @KrzysztofWende: Added another paragraph to the answer, which addresses your question.

Comment: That's just a wild guess because I'm really not good at linux knowledge, but how does SSH do it then?  
When You use SSH the shell is interactive but it doesn't launch explicitly on the other side.

Comment: Because I want a completion inside some language REPL (node, erl shell, ruby etc). Which `compgen` unfortunatelly can't return because it's inside some other environment

Comment: @KrzysztofWende: Your original question showed an attempt to use `bash` to produce the desired completion. So if compgen won't work for you, neither would the pseudocode in the question. If you want to build a REPL, you need to ask a different question. (The answer would probably point you to the readline library.) SSH doesn't do tab-completion; it lets `bash` do it, just like `xterm` does, and using the same mechanism: a pseudo-tty (as mentioned in my original answer.)

Answer (score 0):

I've found an answer.
The thing that made it work was Pseudoterminal.
This module actually.
https://www.npmjs.com/package/pty.js-dl